# How to get result through intent from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using [this cropper](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) library. I want to know from the following chunk of code, how do I get the result of the cropped image's path in a string?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, imageFilePath);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 0);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change `startActivity` with `startActivityForResult`.

If you're done with that, in your activity, override `onActivityResult`, then do

```
String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);
```

where data is the Intent object from `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at [the libraries github page](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage), you should be using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

By calling `startActivityForResult`, once that `Activity` has finished, `onActivityResult` will be called which will then allow you to pull the result out.

The following code is from the README.md of this library:

To start the activity:

```
private void runCropImage() {
    // create explicit intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);

    // tell CropImage activity to look for image to crop 
    String filePath = ...;
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);

    // allow CropImage activity to rescale image
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    // if the aspect ratio is fixed to ratio 3/2
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);

    // start activity CropImage with certain request code and listen
    // for result
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
}
```

Waiting for a result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

        return;
    }  

    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE:

            String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);

            // if nothing received
            if (path == null) {

                return;
            }

            // cropped bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileTemp.getPath());

            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```